# Firebase didn't update the online status using ".info/connected", what is the problem?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android dating app, where I want to show the user online status. Here I use Firebase realtime database technology. But I didn't find any working presence system over the internet. I am stuck in here please help me to solve the issue.

```
public void manageConnections(String gender, String uid){
    DatabaseReference onlineStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(gender).child(uid).child("ol");
    DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: connected");
                onlineStatus.onDisconnect().setValue(false);
                onlineStatus.setValue(true);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: disconnected");
                onlineStatus.setValue(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Step 1 in troubleshooting is to not ignore errors. At its minimum `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: The [sample presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) in the Firebase documentation is quite robust. If you've tried that and can't get it to work, I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line, running in the debugger, and checking the value of each variable on each line. If you do that, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankvanPuffelen now it's working, take 2-3 minutes to update. But it's ok for me.